# Activity Indicator View not spinning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I have below code where I am loading some link in webview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    mySpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [self openWebPage:fileName];
    [self.view addSubview:myWebView];
    [self.view addSubview:mySpinner];
    mySpinner.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0, 100);
}

-(void)openWebPage:(NSString*)address {
    NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:address];
    NSURLRequest*request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    myWebView.scalesPageToFit = NO;

    [myWebView loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {

    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!!!" message:@"Please make sure you are connected to 3G or Wi-Fi." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [errorView show];
    mySpinner.hidden = YES;
    [mySpinner stopAnimating];
}


-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView2 {
    NSLog(@"webViewDidStartLoad");
    mySpinner.hidden = NO;
    [mySpinner startAnimating];
    NSLog(@"step 1");
    NSDate *future = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 2 ];
    [NSThread sleepUntilDate:future];
    NSLog(@"step 2");
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView2 {
    NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad");
    mySpinner.hidden = YES;
    [mySpinner stopAnimating];

}
```

What I am doing is at webViewDidStartLoad I am displaying spinner and starting animating using  `[mySpinner startAnimating];`, but it didn't spin. It just stays as it is (no spinning).

Any idea what is going wrong?

---

### Edit 1

I have webview delegate `@interface WebDetailsViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>`

Also I have added `[NSThread sleepUntilDate:future];` just to verify whether activity indicator view is animating or not.

Below is what I have from NSLog

```
2013-06-23 16:29:28.843 GulfLab[2048:907] webViewDidStartLoad
2013-06-23 16:29:28.845 GulfLab[2048:907] step 1
2013-06-23 16:29:30.847 GulfLab[2048:907] step 2
2013-06-23 16:29:31.836 GulfLab[2048:907] webViewDidFinishLoad
```

---

### Edit 2

Well well well the problem is in below line...

```
[UIView  beginAnimations: @"Showinfo"context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: secondView animated:NO];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Below is what I have...

One first view controller, I have buttons and when I click those button I am coming to second view controller and there I am displaying the web file based on button pressed.

My client wanted some effect while coming to second view and for that I added above code. But because of that, I am facing the activity problem.

Any idea what changes do I need to do?

---

### On further investigation I found that problem is in this line...

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
```

but I need this line as else animation is not happening...

**Also today I noticed that if I touch webview, then it starts animating**

Grrr... someone help me

Comment: Did you forgot to add webview delegate?

Comment: You don't want to sleep on the main thread, as that will block the that thread (upon which UI code runs).

Comment: @Rob : I have added sleep just for checking whether activity indicator is working or not...

Comment: @Swapnil : yes, I have...

Comment: Are you confident that viewWebViewDidStart is actually firing?

Comment: @D80Buckeye : yes, I will update question with output that I have...

Comment: Rather than adding [self.view addSubview:mySpinner];
can you try adding [myWebView addSubview:mySpinner];

Comment: @Swapnil : Still same... :(

Comment: actually in your code you have called 
this line after which you activity indicator will be added can you 
move this line below the adding activity indicator

    [self openWebPage:fileName];  //Move this line below
    
[self.view addSubview:mySpinner];

Comment: Have you tried to just add it to the view and letting it spin to verify that it'S actually placed correctly?

Comment: @FahimParkar "I have added sleep just for checking whether activity indicator is working or not..." That's my point. Putting in a sleep on the main thread _will prevent_ the activity indicator from spinning.  Don't block the main thread. If you want to slow down the `stopAnimating`, then do a `dispatch_after` of that to the main queue, but don't sleep on main thread and expect UI to animate.

Comment: @Rob : see my edit 2, I got the problem and now finding the solution for the same...

Answer (score 23):

If somebody runs into a similar problem where there Indicator is not spinning:

Make sure the `Animating` property is set in your storyboard.

[image: Activity Indicator Animating]

Answer (score 5):

It's possible you aren't getting it to animate because you are not on the main UI thread. Try adding it to a dispatch queue on the main loop to force it on the main loop and it should animate.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [mySpinner startAnimating];
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to put this code after alloc init

```
mySpinner.hidesWhenStopped = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete mySpinner.hidden = YES/NO in your code;

Just add [mySpinner setHidesWhenStopped:YES]; in viewDidload

Then you just start and stop.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    mySpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [mySpinner setHidesWhenStopped:YES];//set Hidden here

    [self openWebPage:fileName];
    [self.view addSubview:myWebView];
    [self.view addSubview:mySpinner];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:mySpinner]; //Add if still not show
}
```

Comment: Maybe your layout bring it outside, test with: mySpinner.center = self.view.center;

Answer (score 0):

I really think the `[NSThread sleepUntilDate:future];` call is killing you in this situation. Most of my code is integration with a 3rd party piece of hardware that will block the main thread in certain scenarios and when that happens I'll have similar behaviors as yours where an element of the UI appears but is in a slightly frozen state until I either tap the screen to "jump start" the UI or the blocking call is completed.

If I were you I would start by getting rid of the `sleepUntilDate` call then remove the call to stop `mySpinner` to make sure it is in fact spinning so that when you run into a longer call of `webViewDidFinishLoad` you'll be assured it's working.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do a pop-up with a spinner in my code. Not exactly what you had asked but it is somewhat similar.

In your *.h file:

```
@interface v3ViewController : UIViewController 
{
    UIAlertView *megaAlert;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIAlertView *megaAlert;

- (IBAction) invokeMegaAnnoyingPopup;
- (IBAction) dismissMegaAnnoyingPopup;
```

In your *.m file:

```
@synthesize megaAlert;

- (IBAction) dismissMegaAnnoyingPopup
{
    [self.megaAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    self.megaAlert = nil;
}

- (IBAction) invokeMegaAnnoyingPopup
{
    self.megaAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please wait..."
                                                message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                      otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [self.megaAlert show];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                                          initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    indicator.center = CGPointMake(130, 70);


    [indicator startAnimating];
    [self.megaAlert addSubview:indicator];
}
```